# Ionic Angular Typescript Export Array

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Typescript get failed to find exported component,May be exported module not appropriatly imported into other component.

It show an error message while call **AddToArray** method:

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

**PageOne.ts**

```
var const array = new Array(5);
export array;
class PageOne {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }   
  GoToPage(){
    this.navCtrl.push('PageTwo');
  } 
}
```

**PageTwo.ts**

```
import { players } from  '../pageone/pageone.ts'

export class PlayersPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) { }
  AddToArray(){
     array.push("TEST") 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, I do not understand why you use the array and export it.
I guess if you just want to make some data type to save and share the data among components.

I would say to use service since each component calls the service to set or get the data from the service.

This doc would be helpful 
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#why-services

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction this is what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you must declare and initialize the array before using it.

```
    class PageOne {
      let navCtrl: string[] =[];

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
      }

      GoToPage(){
        this.navCtrl.push('PageTwo');
      }

    }
```